# MVP and Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection, mvp

I am working on WebForms and i am implementing the MVP pattern. My Presenter is dependent on 5 other classes to perform the actions on my form.

I am using dependency injection to make my code testable. However, my problem is since my presenter is dependent on too many classes I've to inject the dependencies of all these dependent classes in the presenter's constructor. This is a 'Too Many Parameters' code smell.

Guidance needed on how to go about solving this problem.

Help is appreciated.

Regards,
Suyog

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

Comment: Got the idea from this article!! Thanks :)

Comment: Can you post some code that shows the presenter with its dependencies. It's vrry useful to see at least the presenter's constructor. Use the real dependency types if you can (don't make it abstract; context is important).